# Call a function after a certain character has been pressed but only if there is a space before hand

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

I want to call a function after someone has entered an <kbd>@</kbd> symbol and only if there isn't a character before it, but also if the <kbd>@</kbd> symbol is the first character written in the `textarea` also run the function.

Now I know there is the `onkeypress` event in JS and I know the <kbd>@</kbd> symbols unicode character is `64`.

So I could write a function like so

```
keyPress(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 64) {
      // Do Something
   }
}
```

But how do I detect if there is a character before the <kbd>@</kbd> symbol, and I'm just wondering if this `keyPress` event will work properly on mobile?

Just to clarify this is being used in a `textarea`, I've seen that you could possibly use regex but apparently it doesn't work for all browsers? I would need this to work for all browsers plus mobile devices.

This would also have to work multiple times in the same `textarea`, and if the `@` symbol is the first character typed run the function as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What type of field is this? Regular input?

Comment: @GrandIQ its a textarea sorry should of been more specific, Ive updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `keyup` event listener to the `textarea`, check if the last typed character was an `@` and then grab the cursor position from the `textarea` using its `selectionStart` property and then using that and the `textarea`'s value you can determine if the character before the last typed `@` is a space. This works even if the user moves their cursor around in the `textarea` using their mouse, it also works even if they are multiple `@` characters inside the `textarea` already.

Comment: Thanks this works the best so far, I will continue testing and let you know how I go thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One fairly reasonable solution is to listen for keypress events, setting a boolean flag if the character is a space, running your function if the character is an `@` and the flag is set indicating that the previous character was a space, and resetting the flag if the character is anything else.

To continue with your example:

```
let hasSpace = false;
keyPress(event) {
    if(event.keyCode === 32 || event.keyCode === 160) {
        hasSpace = true;
    } else if(event.keyCode === 64 && hasSpace) {
        hasSpace = false;
        // Do something, the previous character was a space
    } else {
        hasSpace = false;
    }
}
```

This will guarantee that the code at `// Do something` will only be run if the current character is an `@` **and** the previous character was a space. Note that I used both `32` and `160` for space, as there are two types of space to account for, breaking and non-breaking.

Comment: This will only work if the last typed character is a space, not if the character before the `@` is a space. For example, this won't work if the user changes their cursor position using their mouse within the textarea.

Comment: @kfedorov91 do you have a better solution?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson yes, I just finished my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51354901/2766908

Answer (score 2):

I gave this a shot and I came up with this

```js
function checkVariable() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("text").value;
  if (textarea.length > 2) {
    var text_length = textarea.length;
    if (textarea[text_length - 1] == "@") {
      if (textarea[text_length - 2].length == 0 || textarea[text_length - 2] == " ") {
        console.log("You typed a @ With a space behind it!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text" onkeyup="checkVariable()"></textarea>
```

Only thing I don't like about it is the fact that it runs on both keyup and keydown, I don't recall the appropriate way to prevent the default action with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah It does run the function twice, any idea on how If @ is the first character it doesnt need a space before it??

Comment: Thats simple, add another if statment and check if (textarea[0] == “@“){ Do something}. Make sure this runs before my second block that checks 1 space behind and convert my first if into else if.

Comment: You can also repeat this one more time with texarea[1] if for some reason someone pressed space beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you *should* be using a regular expression. `Regex.test()` is available in all browsers, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp).

```js
const p=document.querySelector('p'), re=/(^@|\s@)/g;
function check(ta){
 p.innerHTML=re.test(ta.value)
    ? 'invalid input: '+ta.value.replace(re,'<b>$1</b>') // true
    : ''                                                 // false
}
```

```css
b {color:red}
```

```html
<h3>Please type sonme text with @:</h3>
<textarea id="myText" oninput="check(this)"></textarea><p></p>
```

This can of course also be demonstrated in codepen, see [here](https://codepen.io/cars-ten/pen/yqOBBo).

Comment: Doesnt seem to be working properly because if I do a space then @ then another space and keep typing I get true every time

Comment: `true` indicates the presence of a "solitary" `@`, so this is exactly the behaviour I expect. Your input string is "ok" when the function returns `false`.